# How can I solve this math equation in PHP?

Tags: php, math

I am trying to find x in this equation : x + (0.2 * x) = n.
n would be a fixed number like 11 for example.

I tried implementing an equation solving function in php but it did'nt lead to anything.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Show us what you've tried and we can advise

Comment: You have to understand how to solve this problem mathematically before you can try to solve it programmatically.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not here to teach you algebra or write code for you.

Comment: I'm personally and perhaps rather dogmatically opposed to downvoting questions on the grounds of obviousness. I answered this since an "equation solving function" is unnecessary given that the equation simplifies to something simple.

Comment: @MarcB The problem was a mix of php and maths so I did not really know if I should post it here or on mathoverflow.

Comment: @Bathsheba thank you for answering, I have problems with basic algebra like this, I miss some automatisms. I should learn the basics again.

Answer (score 8):

This simplifies to `x = n / 1.2`, which you can implement easily in php.

Note that `x` will not necessarily be a whole number if `n` is.

Comment: What if n is 1200 ;)

Comment: @Dale: Touche. You in Mayfair? If so, I'll buy you lunch.

Comment: Sorry I just had to, I couldn't of figured out the equation so eloquently though